# Relation on a set of relations with these limitsprove equivalence / partial order

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

> Let $S$ be a finite set.
>   Define $\mathscr R(S)$ to be the set of relations on $S$. Define a relation $\mathscr R$ on $\mathscr R(S)$ as follows:
>   $$\mathscr R=\{(\mathscr P,\mathscr Q)\mid \mathscr P,\mathscr Q∈\mathscr R(S),∀\,a,b∈S, \text{ if } a\mathscr P\,b,\text{ then } a\mathscr Q \,b\}.$$

Knowing that $\mathscr P$ is always a subset of $\mathscr Q$, then this relation is

Reflexive:
Because a subset can be a subset of itself, thus $\mathscr P$ and $\mathscr Q$ can be equivalent for every $\mathscr P$.

Symmetric:
Using same logic as above, the only relations that can exist where $(\mathscr P,\mathscr Q)$ exists, $(\mathscr Q,\mathscr P)$ exists when they are equal. Otherwise, when $\mathscr Q$ is a greater subset, it would not be in this relation.

Antisymmetric:
Stated part of above

Transitive:
If a set $\mathscr P$ is subset of $\mathscr Q$ and $\mathscr Q$ is a subset of $\mathscr V$, by standard set logic, $\mathscr P$ is a subset of $\mathscr V$, thus it is transitive.

With all four proven true, then this relation is a partial order (reflexive, transitive, antisymmetric) and a equivalence relation(reflexive, symmetric, transitive).

EDIT: I was just asking if the logic here is sound and true for all those statements?

Comment: Use `$\{a,b,c\}$` to show $\{a,b,c\}$. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here, but just so you know, the power set of any set is a partial order under inclusion. And your $\mathscr{R}$ is just the inclusion relation on $\mathcal{P}(S\times S)$.

Comment: $\mathscr{R}$ is not symmetric.  If $S = \{1, 2, 3\}$, $P = \emptyset$, $Q = \{(1, 2)\}$, then $P \mathscr{R} Q$ but not $Q \mathscr{R} P$.

Comment: Your relation $\mathscr{R}$ is just $\subseteq$, which is a partial order and *not* an equivalence relation on *any* set of sets with more than one member.